# Meaning of GPSDetail fields

Tags: dji-sdk

I am receiving GPS data from an M210v2 drone using the OSDK 4.0.1, and I have several questions about the [GPSDetail struct](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/structDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1Telemetry_1_1GPSDetail.html):

```c
typedef struct GPSDetail
{
  float32_t hdop;       /*!< horizontal dilution of precision */
  float32_t pdop;       /*!< position dilution of precision */
  float32_t fix;        /*!< the state of GPS fix */
  float32_t gnssStatus; /*!< vertical position accuracy (mm) */
  float32_t hacc;       /*!< horizontal position accuracy (mm) */
  float32_t sacc;       /*!< the speed accuracy (cm/s) */
  uint32_t  usedGPS;    /*!< the number of GPS satellites used for pos fix */
  uint32_t  usedGLN; /*!< the number of GLONASS satellites used for pos fix */
  uint16_t  NSV;     /*!< the total number of satellites used for pos fix */
  uint16_t  GPScounter; /*!< the accumulated times of sending GPS data  */
} GPSDetail;            // pack(1)
```

1. The only information that I could find on the values of the "fix" field is [this 2 year old post](https://djisdksupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023651393-What-is-the-Parameter-Range-and-Meaning-of-GPSDetail-fix-?mobile_site=false):

```
0x00:no fix
0x01:dead reckoning only
0x02:2D-fix
0x03:3D-fix
0x04:GPS+dead reckoning combined
0x05:Time only fix
```

Is this still accurate? If so, what does a "time only fix" mean, and can I use the latitude/longitude estimates in that case?

2. Precisely what kind of accuracy measures are given in gnssStatus, hacc and sacc? Are these RMS, 2DRMS, CEP, R95, SEP, or some other statistic? [ref](https://www.gpsworld.com/gps-accuracy-lies-damn-lies-and-statistics/)
3. What are the units of HDOP and PDOP?
4. Is NSV always the sum of usedGPS and usedGLN?